# Inserindo código HTML/Javascript no corpo de um site Wordpress através do Visual Composer

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

Olá!

Estou tentando inserir uma **tabela personalizada** (código html/javascript) no corpo de uma página do meu site Wordpress.

Esta tabela: http://piscinafacil.com.br/tabela2.html

*No momento a tabela está sem a parte de javascript*

Código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Planos Mensais de Limpeza de Piscinas</title>
  <script src="http://s.codepen.io/assets/libs/modernizr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  
<style>

body { background: #fff; font: 400 12px "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif; color: #333; text-align: center; padding: 4em 15em; }

/*TÍTULOS*/
h1 { font-weight: 300; font-size: 5em; line-height: 1.35; margin: 0 0 .125em; }
h1 + p { font-size: 1.5em; color: #999; max-width: 30em; margin: 0 auto 3em; }

/*TABELA*/
table { width: 100%; text-align: left; border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }

/*TABELA - FONTS BASE*/
th { font-family: inherit; font-size: .875em; line-height: 1.45; color: #444; vertical-align: middle; padding: 1em; }
td { font-family: inherit; font-size: 1.5em; line-height: 1; color: #444; vertical-align: middle; } 
th { font-weight: 600; }

/*TABELA - BORDAS INICIAIS*/
colgroup:nth-child(1) { width: 15%; border: 0 none; }
colgroup:nth-child(2) { width: 10%; border: 1px solid #ccc; }
colgroup:nth-child(3) { width: 10%; border: 1px solid #ccc; }
colgroup:nth-child(4) { width: 10%; border: 1px solid #ccc; }
colgroup:nth-child(5) { width: 10%; border: 1px solid #ccc; }

/*TABELA - HEADER*/
thead th { background: #def4fe; background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #f5f5f5 100%); background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f5f5f5 100%); background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f5f5f5 100%); background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f5f5f5 100%); background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#f5f5f5 100%); text-align: center; position: relative; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 3em 0 2em; font-weight: 400; color: #999; }

thead th:nth-child(1) { background: transparent;  }
/*thead th:nth-child(3) {  }*/
thead th h2 { font-weight: 800; font-size: 20px; line-height: 1; color: #59c7fb; } /*Títulos plano*/
thead th h2 + p { font-size: 18px; line-height: 1; } /*Preços plano*/
/*thead th:nth-child(3) h2 {  }*/
/*thead th:nth-child(3) h2 + p {  }*/

/*TABELA - BODY*/
tbody th { background: #fff; border-left: 1px solid #ccc; }
tbody th span { font-weight: normal; font-size: 87.5%; color: #999; display: block; } /*Fonte da descrição dos benefícios*/

tbody td { background: #fff; text-align: center; }

tbody tr:nth-child(even) th,
tbody tr:nth-child(even) td { background: #f5f5f5; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-width: 1px 0 1px 1px; } /*Formatação das linhas da tabela*/
tbody tr:last-child td { border-bottom: 0 none; } /*Formatação da borda do botão comprar*/

/*TABELA - FOOT*/
tfoot th  { padding: 1em 0.5em; border-top: 1px solid #ccc; }
tfoot td  { text-align: center; padding: 1em 0.5em; border-top: 1px solid #ccc; }
tfoot a  { font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; color: #fff; text-decoration: none; text-transform: uppercase; display: block; padding: 1.125em 2em; background: #1bbde8; border-radius: .5em; }


/*CHECKLIST ICONS*/
.fa-check {
  color: #b7e000;
}

.fa-times {
  color: #AF3D11;
}

</style>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <body>
<img src="https://piscinafacil.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/logo-piscina-facil-manutencao-com-responsabilidade-tecnica.png?x63376" height="100px">
  <h1>Planos Mensais</h1>
  <p>Confira nossos planos para todos os tipos de piscina.</p>

Estado 
 <select name="estado"> 
  <option value="estado">Selecione o Estado</option> 
  <option value="ac">SC</option> 
 </select>
<br>
Cidade
 <select name="cidade"> 
  <option value="cidade">Selecione a Cidade</option> 
  <option value="ac">Florianópolis</option> 

 </select>
<br><br>
Tipo de Piscina
 <select name="tipo"> 
  <option value="tipo">Residencial</option> 
  <option value="ac">Coletiva</option> 

 </select>
<br>
Volume da Piscina
 <select name="volume"> 
  <option value="volume">Até 50m²</option> 
  <option value="ac">de 51m² até 100m²</option> 

 </select>

<br><br><br>


 <table>

  <colgroup></colgroup>
  <colgroup></colgroup>
  <colgroup></colgroup>
  <colgroup></colgroup>
  <colgroup></colgroup>

     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>&nbsp;</th>
       <th>
        <h2>VIRTUAL</h2>
        <p>R$ </p>
       </th>
       <th>
        <h2>INVERNO</h2>
        <p>R$ </p>
       </th>
       <th>
        <h2>+ FÁCIL</h2>
        <p>R$ 190,00</p>
       </th>
       <th>
        <h2>ZERO CLORO</h2>
        <p>R$ </p>
       </th>
      </tr>
     </thead>

     <tfoot>
      <tr>
       <th>&nbsp;</th>
       <td><a href="#">ADERIR</a></td>
       <td><a href="#">ADERIR</a></td>
       <td><a href="#">ADERIR</a></td>
                        <td><a href="#">ADERIR</a></td>
      </tr>
     </tfoot>

     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <th>Quantidade de Visitas/Mês </th>
       <td>0</td>
       <td>2</td>
       <td>
                             <form>
                             <SELECT NAME = "menu" SIZE=1>
                             <OPTION>4
                             <OPTION>8
                             </SELECT>
                             </form>
                        </td>
       <td>
                             <form>
                             <SELECT NAME = "menu" SIZE=1>
                             <OPTION>4
                             <OPTION>8
                             </SELECT>
                             </form>
                        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>Quantidade de Visitas/Mês - Supervisor Operacional </th>
       <td>0</td>
       <td>0</td>
       <td>0</td>
       <td>0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>Controle Técnico </th>
       <td><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></td>
       <td><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></td>
       <td><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></td>
       <td><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>Anotação de Função Técnica </th>
       <td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></td>
       <td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></td>
       <td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></td>
       <td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>Análise da Água in Loco <span>Análise dos parâmetros: pH, Cloro Residual, Alcalinidade e Turbidez</span></th>
       <td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></td>
       <td><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
       <td><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></td>
       <td><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>Análise da Água em Laboratório Credenciado </th>
       <td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></td>
       <td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></td>
       <td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></td>
       <td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>Limpeza Física <span>Aspiração, Peneiração, Escovação, Limpeza de bordas, etc...</span></th>
       <td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></td>
       <td><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></td>
       <td><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></td>
       <td><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>Limpeza Química <span>Aplicação de Produtos</span></th>
       <td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></td>
       <td><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></td>
       <td><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></td>
       <td><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>Consultoria Técnica <span>Instalação Elétrica, Hidráulica, Bombas e Filtros</span></th>
       <td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></td>
       <td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></td>
       <td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></td>
       <td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>Assessoria Completa para Regularização da Piscina <span>Vigilância Sanitária e Prefeitura</span></th>
       <td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></td>
       <td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></td>
       <td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></td>
       <td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>Manutenção Preventiva de Filtro e Bomba </th>
       <td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></td>
       <td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></td>
       <td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></td>
       <td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th>Fornecimento de Guardião de Piscinas </th>
       <td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></td>
       <td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></td>
       <td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></td>
       <td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></td>
      </tr>
      </tr>
     </tbody>

 </table>

</body>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

  
</body>
</html>
```

Estou tentando inserir a tabela no corpo de uma página do site feito Wordpress.

O site foi totalmente desenvolvido com auxílio do **Visual Composer**. Estou tentando inserir a tabela através do **raw HTML**, elemento do Visual Composer.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No entanto, ao inserir o código no **raw HTML**, o layout de **TODA a página** acaba ficando desconfigurado (*Menu, font-size, etc*). 
Acredito que o css desta tabela, esteja alterando todo o resto do conteúdo.

Gostaria de saber por qual motivo, este código da tabela inserido no raw HTML, está alterando o layout da página inteira, e de que maneira posso prosseguir para que o código não altere o layout de TODA a página?

Desde já agradeço a atenção!

Comment: alguem para ajudar? :)

Comment: alguem tem algum ideia do q pode ser?

Comment: Provavelmente um `<iframe>` resolvia o problema

Comment: @brasofilo Então, eu consegui inserir por iframe, o que acontece é que utilizando o navegador chrome, as vezes ele bloqueia o conteúdo e diz que a página está tentando carregar scripts de fontes não autenticadas. E com isso a tabela que estou tentando inserir via iframe, fica bloqueada e só será mostrada caso o usuário libere esse conteúdo bloqueado. O problema é que para liberar esse conteúdo a pessoa tem que ir em um "escudo" que é mostrado na barra de endereço do navegador, que deve passar despercebido por muitos usuários. Você sabe por que isso acontece?

Comment: O link do iframe aí na sua pergunta é HTTP e o site roda HTTPS, não seria isso?

Comment: @brasofilo Então, na verdade ali em cima coloquei o link em http, mas dentro do iframe ele está em https. A página em que estou tentando inserir o iframe, é de um site criado no wordpress, e a página que está dentro do iframe, foi desenvolvida sem o auxílio do wordpress, somente html, javascript, css. Porém ela se encontra no mesmo servidor deste site Wordpress.

Página do site wordpress: https://piscinafacil.com.br/residenciais/
(no meio da página está o iframe)

Página da tabela que está dentro do iframe: https://piscinafacil.com.br/tabela_teste.html#